# Model origin dispersion problem

Tags: modeling, export, add-on

I use "Origin to 3D Cursor" make all origin going to cursor middle, after save files and open that file or export to SMD file it all model and origin are dispersed.

Before:
[image]
[image]

After:
[image]

I don't know if this is an addon conflict.

Blender files:

- https://pasteall.org/blend/70706954d37d4854b72cfdb26143d60a
- https://pasteall.org/blend/b98adac7475b4f6cab95f506c10c3ca0

Comment: From your screen it looks like you have set some keyframe in Timeline :) The "after"  you can experience if you move frame +/- to update viewport without reopening.

Comment: oh. I'm delete that all keyframe in timeline and not happen to the "after", and thx to help.